# C++ Async Sockets (System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginAccept) with WinSock2.h

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm currently making a C++ app (to improve my C++).
I'm creating a socket server but I'm stuck.

How I would do it in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Network
{
    class HTcpListener
    {
        private Socket mSocket;

        public HTcpListener(int port)
        {
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            mSocket = new Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.tcp);
            mSocket.Bind(endpoint);
            mSocket.Listen(10);
            mSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept));
        }

        private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult iAr)
        {
            // Handle connection and start up game

            mSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept));
        }
    }
}
```

But now I'm wondering. In WinSock2.h there's a function called accept, but I'm wondering if it works the same as BeginAccept, and if not, how to make it function like it would in my C# example. It must have the ability to handle multiple sockets at the same time + more than 1 socket.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=non+blocking+sockets+winsock

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to use a while/for(;;) loop.

Comment: You need a loop, and you do in fact have one in your C# application. It's hidden inside `Application.Run` which, and I quote the docs, "begins running a standard application message loop".

Comment: Hmm, is there any C++ alternative for the Application.Run? I try to get more than 1 loop (has to be multithreaded so multiple users should receive more packets)

Comment: http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_6.shtm

Comment: [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just using an ordinary blocking [`accept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call on a worker thread to avoid blocking your UI thread.  It's much simpler than dealing with asynchronous sockets.

But if you do need asynchronous sockets, you should use the [`ioctlsocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to make your socket non-blocking.  Then, `accept()` will return immediately with the error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.  You can then use that socket as part of a call to [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`WSAEventSelect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to  test if the `accept()` call has completed or wait on multiple sockets at once.

Once one of those `select`-like calls has indicated that the socket is ready, you can call `accept()` again on the socket, and it should complete successfully without blocking.  You're done!

Comment: *there's no automatic means of having a callback function called* That's what `WSAAsyncSelect` does...

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Oops, you're right, I apparently didn't read the docs for that function carefully.  I haven't ever used that function in practice (just the plain old `select()`).

Answer (score 1):

The APIs that .NET's async sockets use under the hood are [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) combined with [`AcceptEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524.aspx) and friends. These are commonly used in apps requiring high-performance, scalable I/O. These are a bit more involved to use than the .NET wrappers, but you're already halfway there if you're accustomed to .NET's APM pattern.

Adam's suggestion to use a non-blocking socket will work fine too, just with significantly less scalability. Don't let that discourage you from checking them out though, as they're good enough for most apps and more easily ported to what's available on other operating systems.

A more C++-centric and fully portable approach would be something like [Asio](http://think-async.com/), which uses a callback system similar to APM. Highly recommend it.