# Asynchronous c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I am going to create a DLL which is in C++ on windows platform without using any .net library.
There is a client application in my DLL which starts the server and communicating via Socket in worker thread and it blocked at recv() so we cannot do any other operation in my main thread..but in main there are implementation of Callbacks which is called by some other application any time.so i want my worker thread to be asynchronous which works parallely with main thread.i am using Winsock for socket connection.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Also if you want to use boost library see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/design/async.html

Comment: since i am using visual studio 2008 cannot use c++11 feature

Comment: as per requirment i can't use boost library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
To learn how to ask a good question see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In this case it would help if you showed some code, and explained the problem you are encountering.

Comment: See my answer here for a straight-up Win32 solution, no Boost wrappers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19672175/209199

Answer (score 1):

try using non blocking sockets, it is available in WinAPI. a tutorial on it can be found at **http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_3.shtm**
Regards

Comment: Please add more content to the answer than just a link. Link-only answers are discouraged at SO, since each answer should be able to stand for itself. Links also tend to get broken over time. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) for details.